# Permission class on @detail_route not working, Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF, but I'm trying to use a permission class on a @detail_route using the method in this stack thread: [Using a permission class on a detail route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356135/using-a-permission-class-on-a-detail-route)

My code currently looks like this :

```
@detail_route(methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[IsStaffOrRestaurantUser])
def restaurant_dishes_ready_for_pickup(self, request, pk=None):
    ...stuff....

class IsStaffOrRestaurantUser(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print(request)
        print(view)
        print(obj)
        return False
```

The print statements never get executed... I'm probably missing something but I've looked through the documentation and can't really figure it out, is my approach right at all? Thanks!

EDIT:
I realize in our code already that we have this snippet in our Viewset, is it possible to override this in the decorator?

```
def get_permissions(self):
    # Limit to listing and getting for non Admin user
    if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

    return (IsAdminUser(),)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the most *elegant* solution, but you might be able to upgrade `get_permissions()` like so:

```
def get_permissions(self):

    # check additional route specifics
    path = self.request.path
    if ("restaurant_dishes_ready_for_pickup" in path):
        return (IsStaffOrRestaurantUser,)

    # Limit to listing and getting for non Admin user
    if (self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS):
        return (permissions.AllowAny,)

    return (IsAdminUser,)
```

---

PS: Also maybe return permission class objects instead of instances in `get_permissions()`.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions):

> If you're writing your own views and want to enforce object level permissions, or if you override the get_object method on a generic view, then you'll need to explicitly call the .check_object_permissions(request, obj) method on the view at the point at which you've retrieved the object.

So you'll need to call explicitly the permission check.

Note that you could have that for free if you were using a [RetrieveAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) instead of a function based view for example.